# error using subquery

Tags: mysql, subquery

This query does not not work:

```
SELECT
  user.user_id, 
  user.lastname,
  (SELECT
    reg_fee 
   FROM event 
   where event_name = (SELECT event_joined from user)
FROM user WHERE user.registration_type=1 AND user.payment_status=1
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis on the first inner `SELECT`, but I'm not certain this will get what you want anyway.

```
SELECT
  user.user_id, 
  user.lastname,
  (SELECT
    reg_fee 
   FROM event 
   where event_name = (SELECT event_joined from user)
  /* Close the parens and add an alias */
  ) AS reg_fee
FROM user 
WHERE user.registration_type=1 AND user.payment_status=1
```

This can be done a little more cleanly (and probably a lot faster) with a `JOIN`, assuming I gleaned the table structure correctly, and `user.event_joined = event.event_name`

```
SELECT
  user.user_id,
  user.lastname,
  SUM(reg_fee)
FROM user JOIN event ON event.event_name = user.event_joined
WHERE user.registration_type = 1 AND user.payment_status = 1
GROUP BY user.user_id, user.lastname
```

Comment: @user1242749 You're welcome, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  If an answer meets your needs, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark beside it. Cheers.

Comment: Hey Michael, Is it possible to get sum of the reg_fee? If so, how? I actually tried sum(reg_fee) Unfortunately when I do this, the other rows dont get shown.

Comment: @user1242749 Yes, see the changes to my second query above.  You also need a `GROUP BY` clause if you use the aggregate `SUM()`.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you are using this way which is more readable in my opinion:

```
select user.user_id, user.lastname,event.req_fee
join event on (event.event_name = user.event_joined)
from user
where user.registration_type=1 AND user.payment_status=1
```

Comment: dom, thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, like what I posted below on michael's answer, when I used sum(reg_fee) the other fields dont get shown. Do you have any ideas? Am I missing something? Thanks for your effort :)